# AJAX isn't working in my contact form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

When I use the submit button in my contact form downloaded here:

http://resellscripts.info/index.php?route=product/product&path=40&product_id=62

Instead of adding the no error "message has been sent" `div`, it sends me to the `send.php` page.  The contact form can be found here:

[stephenharman.com/sh](http://stephenharman.com/sh)

(click on 'hire me')

Comment: http://stephenharman.com/sh/js/js.js - not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form's jQuery code is inside here, `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/js.js"></script>`, it would need to be included **AFTER** jQuery like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/js.js"></script>
```

<strike>Even so, it's giving me a 404 error so I cannot even troubleshoot further.</strike>

http://stephenharman.com/sh/js/js.js

---

Edited `src` to fix 404 error as per OP's site.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the link check it now :)

Comment: @StephenHarman, it's never going to work the way you have it.  You're using jQuery [within this file](http://stephenharman.com/sh/assets/js/js.js) but you don't yet have jQuery included on your page.  See the first part of my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I feel pretty stupid lol. I never realized header order was important, I always thought when it's loaded, it's loaded. But thanks, a lot!

Comment: @StephenHarman, it's not much different than running a JS when a page loads but before all the elements have been created... you get _"...is not defined"_ errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the ajax from your `js.js` form? If so, it needs to be called after `jquery` and the link isn't correct, so it isn't being called at all.